# core-data hierarchical lists without sharing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to create a simple task list App. Each task has some properties (title, due date etc). Also each task should be able to store more specific work items e.g.

Task1:

- Title=clean house
- dueData=jan 01 2012
- Workitem:

  - 1: Sweep floor
  - 2: Wash floor
  - 3: Do dishes

I have implemented "Task" as an entity and "Workitem" as a different entity. A Task has a To-Many relationship to "Workitem" and there should not be an upper bound to the number of Workitems in each task.

My problem is that when I make a second Task (Do grocery shopping) the Workitems from Task1 show up in the Workitem list for Task2. Any hint to how I can make the Workitems specific to the Task?

An equivalent problem would be creating a list of working units in a company each unit with a list of employees in that department.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be conflating two separate graphs: one being a taxonomy of possible connections and the other being actual objects connected to define a particular task. But it is unclear to me exactly what the problem is.

Do you have specific types of tasks? For example, would a "Clean House" task always have the same three Workitems?

How are Workitems created? Are they user-defined?

Are Workitems meant to be in some way scoped/constrained by the Task? In other words, would "Sweep floor" always be associated with a "Clean House" task? Are you trying to partition Workitems so that (in the UI) only a subset are available/visible at a time?

Comment: The user adds Tasks and for each Task specifies the title, date and the Workitem associated with that task. So in the case of "Clean House" all three Workitems are user-defined and not picked from some predefined or global list. If the user then creates a "Clean House Next Week" task he should again specify all Workitems related to next week's cleaning. So the App should not know that the activities are related (both cleanings task here) and the Workitems list for "Clean my house next week" should be empty to begin with. The user might also add a new Workitem (laundry) to next week's cleaning.

Comment: So, there's no list of pre-existing Workitems when one goes to create a new Task? (Not a criticism - just a question.) But currently, you are seeing that a newly created Task is already associated with Workitems from a previous Task?

Comment: Correct, no pre-existing list of Workitems. Yes currently newly created Tasks see all Workitems from all other Tasks. If a new Workitem is then added in any of the Tasks it appears in all Tasks. So it seems they all point to the same list but I'm not sure why and how to create separate lists.

Comment: Are you sure that you have multiple Tasks - and are not somehow reusing same Task? That would be simplest explanation for "new" Task having relationships with existing Workitems that mirror "old" Task's relationships. NSLog(@" task is %@", theTask) will print out fairly full description of theTask.

Comment: I'll try the NSLog thing a try tomorrow (I'm in Europe). Still it's a bit strange: in my RootView, which shows the list of Task objects, I'm able to correctly show the title and date for each Task (and these are indeed different). So these properties (defined in the Task entity) seem to be ok. Somehow the Workitems (a separate entity) behave differently. By the way, for the NSLog test, do you know how can I access a specific Task (theTask) from the RootView when it's a Managed Object?.

Comment: If your root view controller is a UITableViewController and if it implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, then you could print out each cell's Task by adding NSLog() to -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: ...

Comment: Yes I just solved the problem(s). 1) I had not set up the link between Task and Workitems so I added [managedWorkitemObject setValue:managedTaskObject forKey:@"task"] where "task" is a relationship between a Workitem and a Task in the data model. Using NSLog I found that when viewing a managedWorkitemObject the managedTaskObject was nil 2) My list of Workitems shows all instances in the context i.e. for all Tasks. I found out by setting the table style to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and then showing the name of the Task in cell.detailTextLabel.text. So I need some filtering. Thanks a lot!